# use she-bang in oneliner

Tags: bash

Is it possible to use she-bang in oneliners?

I am trying to run this script from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928004/how-to-enter-ssh-password-using-bash, in one liner.

If I put this in a file, and run it with ./file it works as expected, but how would I be able to run that as oneliner?

This works as a script without any issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

How would I be able to run that from oneliner?

If I try to run

`spawn ssh user@my.server.com; expect "assword:"; send "mypassword\r"; interact`

it returns:

```
bash: spawn: command not found
```

If I try to run

`#!/usr/bin/expect -f; spawn ssh user@my.server.com; expect "assword:"; send "mypassword\r"; interact`

then the whole thing is treated as a comment and nothing happens.

EDIT:

tried running stuff suggested in answers:

```
expect -c `spawn ssh user@server "ls -lh /some/file"; expect "assword:"; send "mypassword\r"; interact`
```

it returned

```
bash: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "assword:": no such file or directory
bash: send: command not found
bash: interact: command not found
expect: option requires an argument -- c
```

When running:

```
$ cat << 'EOF' | /usr/bin/expect -
> spawn ssh user@server "ls -lh file"
> expect "assword:"
> send "password\r"
> interact
> EOF
```

It seems to SSH to server, but doesn't run the command, or it doesn't output any result of it:

it returns:

```
spawn ssh user@server ls -lh file
user@server password
```

When I run it from script:

```
./test
spawn ssh user@server ls -lh file
user@server's password:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 467G Jan  2 00:46 /file
```

EDIT2:

Issue with first command was with backtick instead of single quote, following command works as expected

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@server "ls -lh file"; expect "assword:"; send "mypassword\r"; interact'
```

:

Comment: In your `expect -c` command, you have used backticks in place of single quotes. You also appear to have an extra hyphen i.e. `--c` in place of `-c`. And what is the `"ls -lh file"` doing in there? You don't mention it in your original question.

Comment: I tried the extra hypen when one returned expect: option requires an argument -- c, it was the backticks, when I used single quotes it works as expected thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a one-liner, you'd pass the script as the argument to `expect -c`

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@my.server.com; expect "assword:"; send "mypassword\r"; interact'
```

Note that the shell's quotes are <kbd>'...'</kbd> and <kbd>"..."</kbd>, and expect's corresponding quotes are <kbd>{...}</kbd> and <kbd>"..."</kbd>, so there's some flexibility for passing shell vars and so forth.

But that quickly becomes unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: doesn't work for me; returns bash: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "assword:": no such file or directory
bash: send: command not found
bash: interact: command not found
expect: option requires an argument -- c tried with -f also

Answer (score 1):

`expect` can read its script from the standard input:

```
cat << 'EOF' | /usr/bin/expect -
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
EOF
```

Comment: doesn't work as expected, when doing this it doesn't execute the command I have in ssh, for instance ls $ cat << 'EOF' | /usr/bin/expect -
> spawn ssh user@server "ls -lh file"
> expect "assword:"
> send "password\r"
> interact
> EOF
spawn ssh user@server ls -lh file
user@server password: